# How use I filter in realm when filter data disposed

Tags: .net, xamarin, realm

I have tried filter IQueryable<> in realm collection like this:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public bool IsFilter { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<Model> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<Model> collection)
    {
        var filterCollection = collection;

        filterMessages = filterMessages.Where(IsFilter || !IsFilter && w.IsFilter);

        return filterCollection;
    }
}
```

And when I use `ApplyFilter` I will get `NotSupportedException`

I think it happened because object of `Configuration` already disposed and collected.

How I can use a similar filter?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Note that currently, the property must be the left side of a condition. This means that

```
var oldDogs = realm.All<Dog>().Where(dog => 7 < dog.Age); // INVALID query, do not copy
is illegal and would have to be changed into the equivalent

var oldDogs = realm.All<Dog>().Where(dog => dog.Age > 7); // Fixed
```

https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/api/linqsupport.html

Thank @SushiHangover

But I think "Realm" should give a description message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to filter your Realm model by a bool property that is contains, you are use a Linq Where (`Where(model => model.IsFilter == IsFilter)`)

#### Example:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public bool IsFilter { get; set; }

    public IQueryable<ItemModel> ApplyFilter(IQueryable<ItemModel> realmQuery)
    {
        return realmQuery.Where(model => model.IsFilter == IsFilter);
    }
}
```

#### Sample Usage:

```
// Assuming you have an `Configuration` instance already created:
configuration.IsFilter = true;
realmList.ItemsSource = configuration.ApplyFilter(realmList.ItemsSource as IQueryable<ItemModel>);
```

Comment: Yea, but the problem in an already disposed and collected object

Comment: ```Configuration```

Comment: @Asura why would that object be disposed?